# Fody.PropertyChanged Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, uwp

I've encountered a problem after upgrading from Visual 2015 RC to Full version. Fody.PropertyChanged doesn't work in UWP (it worked with RC). After using reflector there is no raisepropertychanged injection, no warnings, nothing. Any ideas?

EDIT: it doesn't even create FodyWeavers.xml after installing it with new Nuget.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that Nuget deprecated several features for Universal Projects

See here for the full details https://github.com/Fody/UniversalAppSample/